# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named when importing from the sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.8

Good day everyone. I have search every stackoverflow but still nothing works for me.

I have following structure:

```
vision
|_____ main.py
|_____ Classes
      |_________ Rocket.py
      |_________ __init__.py   which is empty
```

Now I want to use class `rocket` which is in  `Rocket.py` in `main.py`

I have tried

```
import Classes.Rocket

import .Rocket

import Rocket
```

In all cases it raises the `ModuleNotFoundError:`

Nothing works. Any suggestion?

Comment: what is your execution file path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have package `Classes`, which has module `Rocket`, which has class `rocket`.

If you want to have `rocket` in your global namespace in main, you do

```
from Classes.Rocket import rocket
```

Or you could import it like you did:

```
import Classes.Rocket
```

But then to use `rocket`, you access it like `Classes.Rocket.rocket`.

P.S. It is common python style guide to name modules lowercase, and classes uppercase. So, I would advice to rename `Classes.Rocket.rocket` to `classes.rocket.Rocket`.

Comment: `from Classes.Rocket import rocket`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Classes'`

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how to reproduce this then. You don't have any other files in your project? What is the contents of main.py and rocket.py?

Comment: I found the problem, its just the thing with the SPYDER IDE -_-

Comment: @MuhammedSamedzade don accept solution if this doesn't solve your problem

Comment: @MuhammedSamedzade you should update your original post, or *post your own answer* explaining what was wrong with Spyder, for future readers.